# What evidence is there for successful posthypnotic suggestion where the subject carries out a suggested action upon a trigger without knowing why?

Tags: hypnosis

What evidence is there for successful posthypnotic suggestion where a subject carries out an action that was suggested to them under hypnosis, not only upon the suggested trigger but also **without consciously knowing, before they do it or at the moment they do it, why they are doing it**? For example they might do it

- when somebody says something to them,
- when they hear a specified non-verbal sound, such as a clap or a whistle, or
- when a certain time of day is reached.

I am interested in the case when in the waking state they do not consciously decide to do the action, and when, in addition to this, it is not the kind of reflex or other action that they would have done normally had it not been for the hypnosis.

This question is not about what goes through their mind after they have done the action, not even very soon after. Perhaps they "find" a rational reason for having done it that does not feature hypnosis, or they may be puzzled about why they did it, or they may reason right away that it must have been suggested to them during hypnosis, or perhaps they suddenly remember the actual making of the suggestion during the hypnotic session. Another possibility is that they don't recognise that they have done it. But that's not the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is hypnosis not mind control?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/18883/how-is-hypnosis-not-mind-control)

Comment: @ChrisRogers - No. The answer to that question is interesting on how some posthypnotic actions are similar to involuntary actions in the subjective assessment of time duration made by their subjects, but there is nothing explicit in it about how the subjects consciously view or do not view the motivation for their actions.

Comment: How about this one: [Is it really impossible for a hypnotist to make a participant do something against their will?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/8967/7001)